# twisted: test if connection exists before writing to transport

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.internet

Is there a possibility to test if the connection still exists before executing a `transport.write()`?

I have modified the simpleserv/simpleclient examples so that a message is being send (written to `Protocol.transport`) every 5 seconds. The connection is persistent.

When disconnecting my wifi, it still writes to transport (of course the messages don't arrive on the other side) but no error is thrown.
When enabling the wifi again, the messages are being delivered, but *the next attempt* to send a message fails (and `Protocol.connectionLost` is called).

Here again what happens chronologically:

1. Sending a message establishes the connection, the message is delivered.
2. Disabling wifi
3. Sending a message writes to `transport`, does not throw an error, the message does not arrive
4. Enabling wifi
5. Message sent in 3. arrives
6. Sending a message results in `Protocol.connectionLost` call

It would be nice to know before executing step 6 if I can write to transport. Is there any way?

**Server**:

```
# Copyright (c) Twisted Matrix Laboratories.
# See LICENSE for details.


from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol


class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    """This is just about the simplest possible protocol"""

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        "As soon as any data is received, write it back."
        print
        print data
        self.transport.write(data)

def main():
    """This runs the protocol on port 8000"""
    factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = Echo
    reactor.listenTCP(8000,factory)
    reactor.run()

# this only runs if the module was *not* imported
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Client:**

```
# Copyright (c) Twisted Matrix Laboratories.
# See LICENSE for details.


"""
An example client. Run simpleserv.py first before running this.
"""

from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol

# a client protocol

counter = 0

class EchoClient(protocol.Protocol):
    """Once connected, send a message, then print the result."""

    def connectionMade(self):
        print 'connectionMade'

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        "As soon as any data is received, write it back."
        print "Server said:", data

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print "connection lost"

    def say_hello(self):
        global counter
        counter += 1
        msg = '%s. hello, world' %counter
        print 'sending: %s' %msg
        self.transport.write(msg)

class EchoFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        self.p = EchoClient()
        return self.p

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection failed - goodbye!"

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection lost - goodbye!"

    def say_hello(self):
        self.p.say_hello()
        reactor.callLater(5, self.say_hello)

# this connects the protocol to a server running on port 8000
def main():
    f = EchoFactory()
    reactor.connectTCP("REMOTE_SERVER_ADDR", 8000, f)
    reactor.callLater(5, f.say_hello)
    reactor.run()

# this only runs if the module was *not* imported
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Does `self.transport.write(data)` return something? If its integers then this could be the number of bytes sent. Also maybe twisted has some functions you can override which are called when a connection is closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Protocol.connectionLost` is the only way to know when the connection no longer exists.  It is also called at the *earliest* time when it is known that the connection no longer exists.

It is obvious to you or me that disconnecting your network adapter (ie, turning off your wifi card) will break the connection - at least, if you leave it off or if you configure it different when you turn it back on again.  It's not obvious to your platform's TCP implementation though.

Since network communication isn't instant and any individual packet may be lost for normal (non-fatal) reasons, TCP includes various timeouts and retries.  When you disconnect your network adapter these packets can no longer be delivered but the platform doesn't know that this condition will outlast the longest TCP timeout.  So your TCP connection doesn't get closed when you turn off your wifi.  It hangs around and starts retrying the send and waiting for an acknowledgement.

At some point the timeouts and retries all expire and the connection really does get closed (although the way TCP works means that if there is *no* data waiting to be sent then there actually isn't a timeout, a "dead" connection will live forever; addressing this is the reason the TCP "keepalive" feature exists).  This is made slightly more complicated by the fact that there are timeouts on *both* sides of the connection.  If the connection closes as soon as you do the write in step six (and no sooner) then the cause is probably a "reset" (`RST`) packet.

A reset will occur after the timeout on the other side of the connection expires and closes the connection while the connection is still open on your side.  Now when your side sends a packet for this TCP connection the other side won't recognize the TCP connection it belongs to (because as far as the other side is concerned that connection no longer exists) and reply with a reset message.  This tells the original sender that there is no such connection.  The original sender reacts to this by closing its side of the connection (since one side of a two-sided connection isn't very useful by itself).  This is presumably when `Protocol.connectionLost` is called in your application.

All of this is basically just how TCP works.  If the timeout behavior isn't suitable for your application then you have a couple options.  You could turn on TCP keepalives (this usually doesn't help, by default TCP keepalives introduce timeouts that are hours long though you can tune this on most platforms) or you could build an application-level keepalive feature.  This is simply some extra traffic that your protocol generates and then expects a response to.  You can build your own timeouts (no response in 3 seconds?  close the connection and establish a new one) on top of this or just rely on it to trigger one of the somewhat faster (~2 minute) TCP timeouts.  The downside of a faster timeout is that spurious network issues may cause you to close the connection when you really didn't need to.